# Target media print in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm currently using lazy load on my website but I want to disable it if the Media is equal to print. I want to check in my if statement whether I'm on @media print. What is the best approach here?

```
init(): void {
    if (window.LazyLoad) {
        this.lazyLoadNativeInstance = new window.LazyLoad({
            elements_selector: '[loading=lazy]',
            use_native: true,
        });
        this.lazyLoadFallbackInstance = new window.LazyLoad({
            elements_selector: '.lazy:not([loading=lazy])',
        });
    } else {
        $('img.lazy').each(function(): void {
            const src: string = $(this).data('src');
            $(this).attr('src', src);
            $(this).addClass('loaded');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a media query matches using [`Window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia), like this:

```js
if (window.matchMedia('print').matches) {
  // Lazy-load the images
} else {
  // Don't
}
```